# how can I fit the widgets to the entire frame to enable resizing in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I have been able to resize the GUI, it stretches left right, and the content resizes the widgets, but there seems to be a cut off point which results in just the GUI widgets resizing, how can I make the widgets of the frame resize over the whole frame...

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('300x300')
        self.container = Frame(self.master)
        self.container.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='NSEW')
        self.container['bg']='skyblue'


        self.chip_frame = Frame(self.container)#,height=100,width=100)
        self.random = Frame(self.container)#,height=100,width=100)
        self.fish_frame = Frame(self.container)#,height=100,width=100)
        self.cat_frame = Frame(self.container)#,height=100,width=100)
        self.cow_frame = Frame(self.container)#,height=100,width=100)
        self.brad_frame = Frame(self.container)#,height=100,width=100)


        self.chip_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='NSEW')
        self.random.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='NSEW')
        self.fish_frame.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='NSEW')

        self.cat_frame.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='NSEW')
        self.cow_frame.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='NSEW')
        self.brad_frame.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky='NSEW',rowspan=2)

        self.fish_frame['bg']='orange'
        self.chip_frame['bg']='pink'
        self.random['bg']='black'
        self.cat_frame['bg']='Blue'
        self.cow_frame['bg']='Green'
        self.brad_frame['bg']='Red'
        for i in range(4):
            self.container.columnconfigure(i,weight=1)
        for i in range(4):
            self.container.rowconfigure(i,weight=1)

root = Tk()
root.title('Nathans APP')
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1) 
app = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean with `there seems to be a cut off point which results in just the GUI widgets resizing`? What in the code you posted demonstrates this?

Comment: It is unclear as to what you are asking. Please, can you explicitly advise what you need help with and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?